# Android RxJava2 notify new data insert into a database

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, reactive

I have an Android Application with a Data layer represented by a database resource accessible with Room. These are two methods of my DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
Flowable<List<UserEntity>> getUsers();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void saveUser(final UserEntity user);
```

My Activity `onCreate` method shows the list of user and let insert a new one with a form. It subscribe the observable like this:

```
mUserViewModel.getUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe (this::populateList)
```

Simplified the view model implementation is

```
public Flowable<List<User>> getUsers(){
    return repository.getUsers();
}
```

Now I would like to know which is the best way to notify my observable when I successfully insert a new User into the database in order to refresh user list?

Is it correct to use a `BehaviorProcessor<any value>`, emit a value every time I successfully insert a new User and observe the BehaviorProcessor as and observable inside for example the switchMap method?

This is an example with a filter:

```
BehaviorProcessor<String> mFilter = BehaviorProcessor.createDefault(DEFAULT_VALUE);

public Flowable<List<User>> getUsers(){
    return repository.getUsers()
        .switchMap(users -> mFilter.map(this::filterList));
}

public void saveUser(User user){
    repository.saveUser(user);
    filter.emit(DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

This way every time I emit a new value the observable is refresh and the subscriber get the new data.

Comment: use: public Completable saveuser(User user). It's easier

Comment: the Flowable returned from `getUsers` will emit a new `List` containing all usres when the data in the table changes (a user is added, deleted or modified)

Comment: @LordRaydenMK This because the Room implmentation does it by itself? What If I don't use room and I create manually a Flowable from an Iterable?

Comment: Yes, the room implementation does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments Room already takes care of emitting an item when the table changes.

To address the other part of your question here is a sample code of a reactive shopping cart. (Items instead of Users)

```
/**
 * Holds a list of items that has been added to the shopping cart
 *
 * @author Hannes Dorfmann
 */
public class ShoppingCart {
  private BehaviorSubject<List<Product>> itemsInShoppingCart =
      BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Collections.emptyList());

  /**
   * An observable to observe the items in the shopping cart
   */
  public Observable<List<Product>> itemsInShoppingCart() {
    return itemsInShoppingCart;
  }

  /**
   * Adds a product to the shopping cart
   */
  public Completable addProduct(Product product) {
    List<Product> updatedShoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();
    updatedShoppingCart.addAll(itemsInShoppingCart.getValue());
    updatedShoppingCart.add(product);
    itemsInShoppingCart.onNext(updatedShoppingCart);
    return Completable.complete();
  }

  /**
   * Remove a product to the shopping cart
   */
  public Completable removeProduct(Product product) {
    List<Product> updatedShoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();
    updatedShoppingCart.addAll(itemsInShoppingCart.getValue());
    updatedShoppingCart.remove(product);
    itemsInShoppingCart.onNext(updatedShoppingCart);
    return Completable.complete();
  }

  /**
   * Remove a list of Products from the shopping cart
   */
  public Completable removeProducts(List<Product> products) {
    List<Product> updatedShoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();
    updatedShoppingCart.addAll(itemsInShoppingCart.getValue());
    updatedShoppingCart.removeAll(products);
    itemsInShoppingCart.onNext(updatedShoppingCart);
    return Completable.complete();
  }
}
```

Code from [here](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/blob/master/sample-mvi/src/main/java/com/hannesdorfmann/mosby3/sample/mvi/businesslogic/ShoppingCart.java).

Comment: Could I use rxjava feature like subscribeOn to run the remove or add product code inside a different thread?

Comment: Yes you can. That probably belongs in the client code - > in the classes that use the shopping cart